# recaptcha error; Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha 2 and getting this weird error:
Notice: file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded in ... on line 38.

the code is:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>

<body>
<?php 
$page="contact";
include("includes/navbar.php"); 
echo '<div id="wrapper">';
  $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => '6LfJnWQUAAAAANMRQApsnetVjggDqnn4hx7Ltbyz',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data)
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<h1>You did not prove you are human.</h1><h2> Please go back and complete the form!</h2>";
        exit();
    } 
    else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
more code here to execute if captcha successfull
```

line 38 that triggers the error message is:

```
$verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

The error message appears whether or not the robot box has been ticked. If the box has not been ticked, the "You did not prove you are human" message appears and if the robot box has been ticked the code is correctly processed, although the error message still appears.

How can I remove the error message?  The site has an SSL certificate so I tried changing :

```
$options = array(
            'http' => array (
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
```

to:

```
$options = array(
            'https' => array (
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data)
            )
        );
```

and that removes the error message, but then the "You did not prove you are human" message appears, even if the robot box is checked.

I am stumped.

Regards

Tog

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I fixed it with:

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
<body>
<?php 
$page="contact";
include("includes/navbar.php"); 
echo '<div id="wrapper">';
  $response = $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];
    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = array(
        'secret' => '6LfJnWQUAAAAANMRQApsnetVjggDqnn4hx7Ltbyz',
        'response' => $_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]
    );
    $query = http_build_query($data);
    $options = array(
        'http' => array (
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n", 
            "Content-Length: ".strlen($query)."\r\n".
            "User-Agent:MyAgent/1.0\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => $query
        )
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $verify = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $captcha_success=json_decode($verify);
    if ($captcha_success->success==false) {
        echo "<h1>You did not prove you are human.</h1><h2> Please go back and complete the form!</h2>";
        exit();
    } 
    else if ($captcha_success->success==true) {
more code here to execute if captcha successfull
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a parameter missing inside your options, try something like this:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array (
                'method' => 'POST',
                'content' => http_build_query($data),
                'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$secretKey  = '------------Your S-Key---------------';
    $token      = $_POST["g-token"];
    $ip         = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
   
    /* ======================= POST METHOD =====================*/ 
    $url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?";
    $data = array('secret' => $secretKey, 'response' => $token, 'remoteip'=> $ip);
 
    // use key 'http' even if you send the request to https://...
    $options = array('http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data),
        'header' => 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $response = json_decode($result);
    if($response->success)
    {
        

             echo '<center><h1>Validation Success!</h1></center>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<center><h1>Captcha Validation Failed..!</h1></center>';
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).